# Some kWin shortcuts does not work in 13.04

Tags: shortcut-keys, kubuntu, kwin

I am fresh new to Kubuntu.

I was looking a way to move focused window as Windows do (Win key + arrow keys change the layout of the window). I found there are options for this in "Global Keyboard Shortcuts" (in KWin tab). Unfortunately, it seems to not work.

For example, "Move Window Down" is "Meta+Down". I believe the "Meta" key is the Window key on my keyboard, and "Down" the down arrow key. But it does nothing. Even if I change the key for Ctrl+Shift+K (I apply the settings each time).

Is the feature broken? Is there another way to do it in Kubuntu (without installing another software).

My Kubuntu version is 13.04 and my keyboard a Logitech k350 (I also tried with the virtual keyboard Kvkbd without any luck).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have similar issue after upgrading to KDE 4.10.2. I'm not sure what's the cause, try this workaround:

```
  setxkbmap us
```

Where "us" would be the short name of layout. In case your're using more variants you can specify it as an extra argument:

```
   setxkbmap cz -variant "qwerty"
```

To check possible options see:

```
   man xkeyboard-config
```

**EDIT:**

**Creating a fresh new user account solved that issue for me.** I've tried before that

```
   mv ~/.kde ~/.kde-tmp
   rm -rf /var/tmp/kdecache-{username}
   rm ~/.ICEauthority
   sudo cp /home/new_account/.Xauthority /home/user/.Xauthority
   chown user .Xauthority
```

none of that helps. In my case the problem was also that I wasn't able to display System Settings > Startup and Shutdown > Service manager. Obviously some crucial part of KDE crashed and many dependent services stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible explanation is that it conflicts some other keys.
Either application-specific, or global ones.

You need to look up the hotkey list if there is anything that grabs your hotkey from the function you want to call. (This happened to me many times in Konsole where Kopete grabbed my shortcuts.)

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was my mistake. The shortcut names start by "Quick Tile Window to..."!

Now there is another problem. I cannot register the numpad keys as shortchuts (numpad1 is interpreted as 1). But it seems to be a [bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=183458) running on KDE since a while. I will survive until it is natively supported.